# Youtube Data API V3 .. Issue in visibility of posted comments

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

The Comments I posted for a video through api were not visible when i checked them as an anonymous user.

I am assuming the comment is treated as spam which is why its not showing up.
If that's the case, can someone please tell me if they know how to post comments without being treated as spam(like what should be the posting rate.. etc)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check this [blog](https://youtube-eng.googleblog.com/2015/04/manage-comments-with-youtube-data-api-v3.html) regarding managing of comments with the YouTube Data API v3. Just [register your application](https://developers.google.com/youtube/registering_an_application) to use the v3 API and then check out the documentation for the  [`Comments`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/comments) and [`CommentThreads`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/commentThreads) resources and their methods.

Note that using [`Comments: markAsSpam`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/comments/markAsSpam) method will mark the comment as spam.

Comment: Thanks for the help but I think this is more about how google thinks a comment is spam and how to avoid being marked as spam.